# Lumen 5.6 Migrate Error Specified key was too long max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, lumen

I use Lumen 5.6 and mysql. when i type "php artisan migrate" following error occur:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t  
oo long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `  
users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

I put following code into "boot" method in the AppServiceProvider

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

but I didn't achieve to any success.

Answer (score 17):

you just need one more step

go to app.php on bootstrap folder and uncomomment or modif this line

```
// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

to this code

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

have a good day

Answer (score 8):

You need couple of things to do. I also faced this issue and fixed it by following these two steps

1. Go to app.php in bootstrap directory and uncomment or modify this line.

   ```
   // $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
   ```
2. Now you need to define `boot()`function in `AppServiceProvider`file

   ```
       public function boot()
       {
          Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
       }
   ```

Then you are good to go!

Comment: @MCFreddie777 glad to know my answer helped you! :)

Answer (score 7):

Go to config in file `database.php` then edit

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Comment: this is sub optimal solution because utf8_unicode_ci is a limited (to 3 bytes) charset

Comment: I don't even see this file in my Lumen project.

Answer (score 7):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot(){
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

//rollback your migration or delete all table from database then migrate again.
```

Answer (score 3):

1. in bootstrap/app.php un-comment this line:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

2. in app/AppServiceProvider.php add below public function to `AppServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot()
  {
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Known to work in Laravel/Lumen 7.x:

I've tried the un-commenting of `AppServiceProvider::class` and other solutions mentioned above, but the following worked for me.

If you look in `/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php` for `charset` and `collation`, the code checks your `.env` file and resorts to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, respectively.

If your database' charset is set to `utf8` and collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`, simply add the following to your `.env` file:

```
# .env
...
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci
...
```