# When I try to Migrating my Laravel database I get the error "alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)"

Tags: laravel-5

I have one issue on my Laravel database migration when I try to migrate my database table using this cmd command: PHP artisan migrate then below error is displayed.

```
alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)
```

Do I have to change anything in my user's table file or is there any other setting?

Comment: check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24711 for explanation

Comment: Hey @Gaurav Gupta thanks buddy but now its resolved with the help of pixlogix

Comment: it's just for explanation nothing more to it. :)

Comment: Yes I check that and its help thanks buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit: [Lumen 5.6 Migrate Error Specified key was too long max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169760/lumen-5-6-migrate-error-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot(){
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for your answer can you please explain to me a bit off hope you don't mind thanks in advance

Comment: open the App/providers/AppServiceProvider.php, and put the code 
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;" in top and then put "Schema::defaultStringLength(191);" in boot() function

Comment: Thanks a lot @pixlogix Its work for me have a grate day hola